# Inputting from html to csv via php

Tags: php, html, forms, sass, export-to-csv

So I was experimenting with csv exporting from html and found that php was the best way to do it and that there's actually a dedicated php function for this. However im having issues with the inputting, I'm fairly new to php so its not my strong point so i just copied php's example from their site to get it working. However it isn't working, maybe because of issues in html or php I'm not sure.

Also side note once i get this working, am i able to grab the inputs with $_post['content'] and insert that into the $keys array and will that work the same as just inputting 'strings'

```js
<?php
/*
    $name = $_POST['name']
    $country = $_POST['country']
    $email = $_POST['email']



$keys = array($name, $country, $email);



    $csv_line = array();
    foreach($keys as $key){
        array_push($csv_line,'' . $_GET[$key]);
    }
    $data = 'data.csv';
    $csv_line = implode(',',$csv_line);
    if(!file_exists($data)){$csv_line = "\r\n" . $csv_line;}
    $fcon = fopen($data,'a');
    $fcontent = $csv_line;
    fwrite($fcon,$csv_line);
    fclose($fcon);




    echo file_get_contents($data);
    */
    $list = array (
        array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
        array('123', '456', '789'),
        array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
    );
    
    $fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w');
    
    foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

```css
@import "shortcuts.scss";

*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    form{
        @include flex-pos(column);
        input{
            margin: 30px auto;
            font-size: 200%;
        }
        button{
            @include box-props(block, grey, 100px, 300px, 20px);
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 3em;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<title>CSV test</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name" name="name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="country" id="country" name="country">
        <input type="text" placeholder="email" id="email" name="email">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="functions.js"></script>
</html>
```

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 () VM9:2762 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

Comment: "Not working" does not work, as a problem description. _Explain_ how exactly it is not working. That the code currently doesn't care for any values that might have been submitted via any form is clear, no? You have the first half of the script that _tries_ to access POST parameters, commented out ...

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()
VM9:2762 

crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

Thats the response in the console

Comment: 405 Method Not Allowed is usually what you get when you try to POST data to what the webserver considers to be a "static" resource. Are you sure you have yours properly configured to execute PHP code in files ending `.php` to begin with?

Comment: as for the commented out variables im not too fussed about at the moment, as long as it works i should be able to put inputs into the array, but the issue as mentioned in comment above is breaking the submission.

Comment: WHat issue? The uncommented code runs just fine and creates a little csv file. So again, what EXACTLY is your issue?

Comment: If it works for you guys i Think the issue is because im not running a server, I'm working on this locally at the moment so when i set up my subdirectory i can just slot the code in. Is there anyway i can run either CSV or SQL locally to test before uploading to server?

The only error im getting is the 405 as mentioned above and i believe CBroe is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want the commented code to work, and you want that to add a line to a csv file each time the user submits the form

There is a function specifically written to help with creating CSV files, [See `fputcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

```
    // it would be advisable to check HERE that all the 3 $_POST values actually existed before proceeding


    $titles = ['name', 'country', 'email'];
    $filename = 'data.csv';

    if(!file_exists($filename)) {
        // write the title line as this is the first time we did this
        $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
        fputcsv($fp, $titles);
        fputcsv($fp, [$_POST['name'], $_POST['country'], $_POST['email']);
    } else {
        // add a new line to the bottom of the file
        $fp = fopen($filename, 'a');
        fputcsv($fp, [$_POST['name'], $_POST['country'], $_POST['email']);
    }
    
    fclose($fp);
```